# Brillouin Zone Summation

Tags: condensed-matter, crystals

If one has the following summation:

$$\frac{1}{A}\sum_{\vec{k}} F(\vec{k})$$
which is taken over all k-space and $A$ is the area of the unit cell from the system itself. I want to them limit this to be only over the first Brillouin zone (BZ). Which one can take the sum $\sum_{\vec{k}} F(\vec{k})$ to an integration term which would give $$ \frac{1}{\Delta \vec{k}} \int_{FBZ} F(\vec{k})d\vec{k} $$
where $\Delta \vec{k}=\frac{(2\pi)^2}{A}$ i.e the area of the BZ.
If I now wanted to change this integration back to a summation only over the first BZ, such that I can sum over the k-points in a generated k-point grid. Does the following hold:

1. One can take the term: $\frac{A}{(2\pi)^2}  \int_{FBZ} F(\vec{k})d\vec{k} = \sum_{k} w(\vec{k})F(\vec{k})$ where $w(\vec{k})$ represents the weighting/normalisation factor of the related k-points. If we do not link via symmetrical means we can take to be $\frac{1}{N}$ for all k-points (where N is the number of k-points in the generated grid).
   Hence, $\frac{A}{(2\pi)^2}  \int_{FBZ} F(\vec{k})d\vec{k} = \frac{1}{N}\sum^{FBZ}_{k}F(\vec{k})$

2. Does this then imply in my case above that the summation $\frac{1}{A}\sum_{\vec{k}} F(\vec{k})$, can be reduced simply to over the BZ to:
   $$\frac{1}{A}\sum_{\vec{k}} F(\vec{k}) \Rightarrow \frac{1}{A N}\sum^{FBZ}_{\vec{k}} F(\vec{k}) $$

where $A$ is the area of the unit cell (the system we are looking at in 'real space') and $N$ is the number of k-points in the generated k-point grid for the BZ

Comment: What is $F$ here? In particular what does it do outside the first BZ?

Comment: F is a periodic function in reciprocal space. Which arises due to the k-point grid chosen. (i.e Monkhorst-Pack)

Answer (score 0):

Building on what was said in the comments, $F$ is periodic in reciprocal space, that is
$$
F(\vec{R}+\vec{k}) = F(\vec{k})
$$
where $\vec{R}$ is a reciprocal lattice vector. We can therefore write
$$
\vec{k} = \vec{R} + \vec{q}
$$
where $\vec{q}$ is in the first Brillouin zone. This allows us to separate the sum
$$
\sum_\vec{k} F(\vec{k}) = \sum_\vec{R}^\mathbf{RL}\sum_\vec{q}^\mathbf{FBZ} F(\vec{R} + \vec{q}) = \sum_\vec{R}^\mathbf{RL}\sum_\vec{q}^\mathbf{FBZ} F(\vec{q})
$$
The sum over reciprocal lattice vectors will give you a UV divergent, but constant, prefactor which will be cut off by the short length scale *within* a real unit cell

Comment: how would you go about computing the sum over the reciprocal lattice vectors? Also, would the final sum over the FBZ, can that then be directly computed? do we still need the weighting factor I mentioned of 1/N?

Comment: The sum $\sum_\vec{R}^\text{RL} 1$ is divergent. You either need to find a way to normalize it away (i.e. if your original expression was $S(\alpha)$ depending on  some parameter $\alpha$, then $S(\alpha)/S(\alpha_0)$ will not have the divergent prefactor) or find some way to cut off the sum so that you don't consider reciprocal lattice vectors (or your original $\vec{k}$s) all the way out to infinity. This is equivalent to introducing some short distance cut off in real space, ideally much shorter than the lattice spacing

Comment: In addition, if the bigger picture of this calculation relates to a part of calculating an expectation value over the FBZ, is it suitable to discount all the summation outside the FBZ?

Comment: It is really not possible to say without knowing exactly what the calculation you are trying to do is